# create a dictionary out of two columns with a unique key and list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Am trying to create a dictionary with a unique key and multiple values

Df :

```
key value
2   21
2   32
2   455
3   12
3   45
3   21
```

Expected output:

```
{'2' : ['21', '32', '455'], '3': ['12','45','21']}
```

code :

```
dict(zip(df['key'], df['value']))
```

need some help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First aggregate list by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then convert `Series` to dictionary by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('key')['value'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{2: [21, 32, 455], 3: [12, 45, 21]}
```